# Bash array length always gives me as 1

Tags: bash

I had written a bash script as below.

```
...file1.sh..

read samplearrrr;
echo "*******************"
echo ${#samplearrrr[@]}
echo "*******************"
```

From terminal I run it as ./file1.sh, and give the input to read as 23 45 67 88,

The length in the output is always getting as 1.

I tried to google it, but did not find a solution.

Comment: You have created a variable not an array, and you have only added one element to it.

Comment: So, if we need to get the elements given in terminal at runtime, then we need to split those elements based on the space and store in another array. Is that right ?

Comment: Try `help read` rather than google: *Options:* `-a array` *assign the words read to sequential indices of the array*

Answer (score 1):

Your code reads a words into a variable as a single string.  It will not automatically be converted into an array.

In `bash`, you may use `-a` with `read` to read the values into an array:

```
read -r -p 'enter array values: ' -a vals
printf 'I got %d values\n' "${#vals[@]}"
```